# How do you get this function to read more than one selection?

Tags: javascript, html

I am using this function to output a selected option to an alert from a scrolling list:

```
var topping = "";
            function toppingTotal() {
                var top = document.getElementById('topList');
                if (top.selectedIndex > 0) {
                    topping = topping + "Toppings: " + top.options[top.selectedIndex].text;
                    return topping;
                }
            }
```

Code works fine, but how do I get this to output multiple selections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you have a select with attribute `multiple`. You can try this

```
for (var i = 0; i < top.options.length; i++) {
    if (top.options[i].selected) {
        topping  += top.options[i].text + " ";
    }
}
return topping;
```

For reference - http://plnkr.co/edit/j2PgGy6FJsuLvKSxSOIZ?p=preview

Comment: In place for the current if statement? Wasn't able to get it to work. And yes, I have the attribute multiple.

Comment: @RockGuitarist1, add `return topping;` below this code... Sometimes you need to do a bit more than copy/paste

Comment: @RockGuitarist1 - Yes. It seems to work fine for me. I have added a working version and as my fellow friend suggested to add the return statement, I have updated the answer. You can check now

Comment: It worked. I just missed a closing }. Thank you sir.